# Using JQuery AJAX to submit a form to PHP ,empty value

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a script, submit it does not POST value:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#addProductForm-<?php echo $row_ks['id']?>').validate({
        rules: {
            nguoilienhe: "required",
            soluongphong: "required",
            ngaynhanphong: "required",
            ngaytraphong: "required",
            email: {
               email: true
            },
            songay: {
                required: true,
               number: true
            },
            songuoi: {
              required: true,
               number: true
            },
            nguoilon: {
               number: true
            },
            treem: {

               number: true
            },
            sodienthoai: {
              required: true,
               number: true
            }                               
                },
                messages: {
                   nguoilienhe: "Nhập tên người liên hệ",
                    soluongphong: "Nhập số lượng phòng đặt",
                    ngaynhanphong: "Chọn ngày nhận phòng",
                    ngaytraphong: "Chọn ngày trả phòng",
                    email: {
                           email: "Nhập đúng định dạng mail"
                        },
                        songay: {
                            required: "Số ngày không được rỗng",
                           number: "Nhập kiểu số"
                        },
                    songuoi: {
                          required: "Nhập số người ở",
                           number: "Nhập kiểu số"
                        },
                        nguoilon: {
                           number: "Nhập kiểu số"
                        },
                        treem: {
                           number: "Nhập kiểu số"
                        },
                    sodienthoai: {
                      required: "Số điện thoại",
                      number: "Nhập kiểu số"
                    }
                },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            // comment out AJAX for demo
             $('#img_<?php echo $row_ks['id']?>').show();
            var formData = new FormData(this);
            $.ajax({
            url: 'booking.ajax',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function () {
                //alert('Form Submitted!');

                $('#img_<?php echo $row_ks['id']?>').hide();
                $('#addProductForm-<?php echo $row_ks['id']?>')[0].reset(); 
                //console.log(formData);

                $("#info-<?php echo $row_ks['id']?>").show();
                $("#info-<?php echo $row_ks['id']?>").delay(6000).fadeOut();
            },
            error: function(){
                $("#error-<?php echo $row_ks['id']?>").show();
                $("#error-<?php echo $row_ks['id']?>").delay(6000).fadeOut();
            }
        });
            //alert('form submitted via ajax');
            return false; 
        }
    });

});
```

How to submit from all POST value

Comment: you said you are submitting form to php uisng jquery-ajax but in $.ajax() function your url is pointing to booking.ajax. how can php file recieve any post values if you are not setting url to php file location which process submitted form data.

Comment: Thanks for answering !, The URL pointing to booking.ajax is understood as the URL component / com_postad_manager / com_postad_manager.ajax.booking.php. This is handled in the index.php file by .htaccess

Comment: View error http://sv1.upsieutoc.com/2017/08/20/jquery.png